# Firewall Logs in pfSense shows the WAN IP for NAT Connections

Tags: firewall, logging, pfsense

I have a hardware router running pfSense (version 2.3.2-RELEASE), and I am trying to get the Firewall configured. So far, I only have 2 ports connected, one for the WAN connection, and one for LAN. I presently only have 1 device connected on the LAN.

When I don't have any rules in the Firewall, and I try to ping google, I get no-result (as expected), and the logs show the Source IP address of the blocked connection is the LAN IP (in this case, `10.0.50.30`).

However, when I create a rule in the LAN to allow connections from `10.0.50.30` to `*`, the Firewall logs show the Source IP address is the Routers WAN IP (in this case, `192.168.0.22`), and the Interface that the rule was applied to has changed from `LAN` to `WAN` (`WAN0` here, but that is just future naming for myself).

Additionally, I have opted for the Firewall Logs setting to show me the Rule that passed/blocked the connection in question, however it only shows one of the following:

- let out anything from firewall host itself (10000010111)
- Default deny rule IPv4 (1000000103)

[image: screenshot from the firewall logs]

Does anyone know what I need to change so that when a firewall rule passes a connection, it displays the LAN IP as the Source, instead of the NAT'd WAN IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong in the end.

I had to go to the `Firewall` > `Rules` page, then for each Rule I was interested in getting REAL information for, I checked the `Log packets that are handled by this rule` checkbox, and now when a connection is allowed out through the Firewall, the correct rule description is shown, and the actual source IP is displayed.

[image: The <code>Log packets that are handled by this rule</code> option]

[image: The Firewall log showing the entry for the passed rule]